# How can I have a randomly generated image be used as a tool that a player could use to determine which "character" to press?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In this particular code, I have 3 boxes that currently show up on the screen. The boxes in the center of the screen are the ones I want to have treated as the characters. The box on the top of the screen randomly generates an image of one of the characters, in this case the red box or the blue box. For example, if at the top the red box was selected as the randomly generated image, I would want the player to tap the red box that would be treated as a character. If the person tapped the correct box as a result of the box on the top, I would want the box at the top to change again, therefore creating a cycle between the characters and the box at the top. If the player taps the wrong box, I would want the game to end. What am I doing wrong, and more importantly how can I fix it? Here is my code:

```
local imageFiles = {"bluebox.png", "redbox.png"}
local imageFile = imageFiles[math.random(2)]
local randomImage = display.newImage(imageFile, 40, 40)

local button1 = display.newImage("redbox.png")
button1.x = centerX
button1.y = centerY
group:insert(button1)

local button2 = display.newImage("bluebox.png")
button2.x = centerX
button2.y = centerY - 100
group:insert(button2)

local function randomize(event)
    if button2 == randomImage then
        (insert code here)
     end
end

local function generate(event)
    if button2 ~= imageFile then
        storyboard.gotoScene ("restartEasy")
    elseif button2 == imageFile then
        (insert code here)
    end
end

button1:addEventListener("tap", randomize)
button2:addEventListener("tap", generate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if button2 ~= imageFile then
elseif button2 == imageFile then
```

You're comparing images with strings. This will never work. But let's ignore that for now.

While I'm not familiar with Corona, I believe `randomImage` will never equal either `button1` or `button2` because it's a separate image (with independent coordinates and/or dimensions).

I'd replace your random selection code (the first three lines) with the following lines right after the second call to `group:insert()`:

```
local one_or_two = math.random(2)

local endGameButton, shuffleButton

if one_or_two == 1 the
  endGameButton, shuffleButton = button1, button2
else
  endGameButton, shuffleButton = button2, button1
end
```

At the end I'd replace your two `addEventListener` lines with:

```
shuffleButton:addEventListener("tap", randomize)
endGameButton:addEventListener("tap", generate)
```

And then I'd remove all the conditions (`if buttonX == whatever`) from your functions because they are no longer needed.

In other words: instead of testing which button is the random one every time something is clicked (as you're doing now), we assign each button a meaning.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i'm still confused. How is someone going to know which button to push,  Two, what if I want to add more than two buttons? and 3 do I put the top line of code that you suggested in the function, because how else is the game going to know when to end or not?

Comment: @Andrew Timms: "How is someone going to know which button to push". He won't know. As I understood it, you had two buttons (one for closing, and one for shuffling the positions), and you wanted to decide which button was which randomly.

Comment: Well the point of the game was to have the results of the randomly generated image determine which button needed to be pushed, but you said that wasn't possible.

Comment: @Andrew Timms: "have the results of the randomly generated image determine which button needed to be pushed". Indeed, that's the solution I gave you. You said nothing about the user having to know which button to press. The only difference between the buttons is their color. I got the impression it's supposed to be some sort of "Russian roulette". You may want to edit your question to explain better what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in order to have the top button correspond with the characters, I needed to use the png files of the images as opposed to using a variable defined by those png images. in this case instead of using 
    if button2 = randomimage
use
    if imageFile = "nameofimagefile.png"